# How do I create a stored procedure that retrieves highest Customer ID, adds 1 to it then displays that to textbox?

Tags: sql

How do I create a procedure in that retrieves the highest Customer ID from my Customer Database, adds 1 to it then displays it to the textbox assigned for Customer ID (txtCustID) for a new customer entry?

Comment: A stored procedure can't display anything to anywhere. You need some additional code somewhere to do that.

Comment: ***WHAT*** concrete database? SQL is just the query language - but you should tell us whether you're using `oracle`, `sql-server`, `mysql`, `postgresql` or something else entirely...

Answer (score 1):

Use `AUTO_INCREMENT / IDENTITY` (depending on DBMS being used MySQL or SQL Server ) property on CustomerID column . Using stored procedure to do waht you are trying is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

YOU CAN TRY SEQUENCE IN THIS SCENARIO. USE OF SEQUENCE IS MUCH EASIER. THE NEXT VALUE CAN BE FETCHED BY USING

```
SEQUENCE_NAME.NEXTVAL;
```

SO YOUR CODE WILL BE SOMTHING LIKE THIS

```
TEXTBOX1.VALUE = SEQUENCE_NAME.NEXTVAL;
```

HOPE THIS WILL BE HELPFUL TO YOU.